# Set the name of a ZIP downloadable from GitHub or Other ways to enroll Google Transit project on GitHub

Tags: github, zip, githooks

I wan to start a Google Transit project (a city transport feed for google maps) and for the purpose of collaboration I want to use GitHub. Now one great thing is that GitHub is offering a ZIP file download that contains all your repository, and Google wants a ZIP with a required data, but that file should have name: `google_transit.zip`.

So my question is:
Can I somehow give Google a link that will give it a file called `google_transit.zip`, that will contain all the stuff that's in the master branch? Maybe this can be done with standard "download zip" option or with some hooks or something else…

Answer (score 1):

GitHub will allow you to automatically download a Zip archive of the latest version of a branch using the following url:

> https://github.com/:user/:repository/zipball/:branch [GET]

The archive will be given a special name following the `git describe` command output.

However, there's one way to achieve what you're after by leveraging the **[GitHub Repo Downloads API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/downloads/)**.

Every time your master branch is ready to be published, you'd execute the following steps:

- If the download resource `google_transit.zip` already exists, remove it
- Create a new download resource and name it `google_transit.zip`
- Upload the latest zip archive using the provided information of the previous request

There's even a Ruby library (**[ruby-net-github-upload](https://github.com/Constellation/ruby-net-github-upload)**) that may help you automating this task.

Comment: Thank you for reply and sorry for my inactivity. One more question is: can I do something like this in `post-receive` hook? so the download will be cleared and re-generated after every push to master?

Comment: Yes. You'd have to host that logic (removal of previous archive, retrieval and renaming of current HEAD archive, upload of the new archive) on an Internet accessible endpoint, then let GitHub **[notify this endpoint](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/)** that a push event occurred.